# How can i use % with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am trying to make a HTTP request to a API with a route like this:

[https://example.test/{ID}/get](https://example.test/%7BID%7D/get)

The problem is, the ID starts with %, something like "%123123123", after the "excute" method, locate in RestTemplate class, this ID's becomes %25123123123, % changes into %25.
More specific, in this line of the method:

```
URI expanded = getUriTemplateHandler().expand(url, uriVariables);
```

Here my uriVariables is just a empty Object, and when i manually change the value of expanded variable removing "25", the request works just fine.

Anyone knows how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Spring 5, the **DefaultUriBuilderFactory**, used by **RestTemplate**, defaults is ***EncodingMode.URI_COMPONENT***, as described below:

> Expand URI variables first, and then encode the resulting URI component values, replacing only non-ASCII and illegal (within a given URI component type) characters, but not characters with reserved meaning.

If you want your URI to be unencoded like I do, just create a new **DefaultUriBuilderFactory** with ***EncodingMode.NONE*** and add it to your **RestTemplate**:

```
DefaultUriBuilderFactory uriBuilderFactory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
uriBuilderFactory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.NONE);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(uriBuilderFactory);
```

You can check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.html) for other EncondingModes.